# Updating an input's value without losing cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to mandate that the value of a text box is lowercase using JavaScript. I've tried the code below, but the cursor jumps to the end of the input every time you press a key. How can I avoid this?

```
$("#beLowerCase").keyup(function(){
    $(this).val( $(this).val().toLowerCase() );
});
```

Comment: Preserve the selection range and restore it after setting the value?

Comment: yes!! it will happen because what you are doing!! basically you dont want to change the whole val(). find a way to just change the key pressed and not the whole value

Comment: Might be simpler to just lower-case the value on blur.

Comment: @MikeChristensen that doesn't work for what I'm doing, unfortunately.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
$("#beLowerCase").on('input', function(){

    // store current positions in variables
    var start = this.selectionStart,
        end = this.selectionEnd;

    this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();

    // restore from variables...
    this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
});
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3vpyhnk/))

---

This actually works with CSS as well:

```
#beLowerCase{
  text-transform:lowercase;
}
```

And server can take care of the actual lower-casing...

Comment: luckily, I don't have to care about IE :)

Comment: @onetrickpony, If this only works onkeyup, what happens when the user right click paste?

Comment: There is a reason why I hate jQuery, it's because everyone uses it when it's not really necessary at all.

Comment: Note that when you're using jQuery selector, you need to call `selectionStart` on the DOM element. That means you need to do `$("#someId").get(0).selectionStart`.

Comment: For Safari: do not trigger this lowercasing function with `onblur`, because otherwise the input will keep the focus forever

Comment: Don't forget to take in account the changed cursor position when using this technique to strip characters. If the length of the value changes before setting the selectionRange, the difference in length should be substracted from the start and end of the selection.