# Capitalize first letter in a string (with letters and numbers) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can some please suggest how to capitalize the first letter in a string (using jQuery) with

```
a. 'letters & numbers'
or
b. 'only letters'
```

example:

```
1. Convert from '50newyork' to '50Newyork'
2. Convert from 'paris84' to 'Paris84'
3. Convert from 'london' to 'London'
```

I looked at various examples on SO with no success.

Comment: how about a sentence like "hello everyone."? do you want it to be "Hello Everyone" or "Hello everyone"?

Comment: This looks like what you're looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14688341/2040509

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `replace` method:

```
function cap(str) {
    return str.replace(/([a-z])/, function (match, value) {
        return value.toUpperCase();
    })
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/LuF2e/)

**Edit**: In case you have a string containing multiple (space-separated) words, try something like:

```
function cap(str) {
    return str.split(' ').map(function (e) {
        return e.replace(/([a-z])/, function (match, value) {
            return value.toUpperCase();
        })
    }).join(' ');
}
```

This would convert `"50newyork paris84 london"` to `"50Newyork Paris84 London"`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/LuF2e/1/)

Comment: It works perfectly, I really wished to convert a string from a. '50NewyOrk' to '50Newyork', b. 'lonDon' to 'London' as well..