# How to capitalized only first letter of sentence in input fields with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have only first letter of the sentence to be capitalized in input fields with javascript when i type something.

This is my website [link](http://web.quick-truck.com/signup) where i want to use it.

Is there any solution for it?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="name" class="label-head">Company Name <sup><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk red" aria-hidden="true"></span></sup></label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control text-box-length input-lg" id="companyname" placeholder="Enter Your Company Name" data-validation="required" maxlength="50">
</div>
```

Comment: dublicate [Convert first letter to uppercase on input box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688141/convert-first-letter-to-uppercase-on-input-box)

Comment: This is not duplicate because i want only first letter to be capitalized not every single word..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this function and set the text to input on each key press

```
function titleCase(string) { 
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1); 
}
```