# Force first letter uppercase in input field

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing some JavaScript and would love to hear your thoughts regarding this script I wrote. I've managed to make this work. The script makes the first letter of the input value uppercase using the script below. I'm just wondering if this is a good method of doing this/if my steps are in good order just to get better
love to hear more ways of doing so, even making an option to eliminate the caps-lock via keyboard thanks,

```
// my input var
var strInput =document.querySelector("#inputText > input");

// my function and eventlistener
strInput.addEventListener('input',function() {
    //upper case first letter with concatenate string input 
    var outputString = strInput.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strInput.value.slice(1);
    this.value = outputString;
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert first letter to uppercase on input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688141/convert-first-letter-to-uppercase-on-input-box)

Comment: There is some inconsistency, you access the same object via `this` _and_ via the existing reference, just use the reference. Also you can leverage syntactic sugar to make the code more readable. `strInput.value = strInput.value[0].toUpperCase() + strInput.value.substr(1);`

Comment: @AluanHaddad using `this` in the present position is perfectly fine

Comment: @osherez Your code is fine. just `outPut` seems kinda odd since "output" is one word. Also you should indent your code properly!

Comment: @zeropublix he asked how it could be improved and the use of `this` is inconsistent at best because he already has a reference to the element.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Codereview

Comment: Hey Guys, thanks to all really appreciate the help. 
I'm just wondering how can I take one step up by preventing the caps -look key to overwrite this function
and how can I make this function work on the entire site in section there is input? cheers

Comment: @osherez for the whole page just use a more generalized selector like `document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']")` and the simple run a for-loop to loop through all found elements and bind the event to it.

Comment: @ zeropublix thanks man learnt a lot , I will appreciate if you could you give an example on how you "bind the event to the loop" cheers my friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments requested

Here is an example to bind the event to ALL text-inputs (except `<textarea>` and `contenteditable="true"`)

```
var txtInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text'");

//just a simple validation if its not null, undefined or empty
if (txtInputs && txtInputs.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < txtInputs.length; i++) {
        var txtInput = txtInputs[i];

        txtInput.addEventListener('input', function() { 
            var outputString = this.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.value.slice(1);
        });
}
```

Comment: you are a magician my friend, now I understand what you meant. loved how you validated with the if statement, I didn't think of that. basically this validation is a just  "safety precautions" to see if there such inputs in the markup right? cheers man learnt a lot from this.

Comment: The if-condition is used to fullfill "all pathes". If there is existing elements `<input type="text" />` it's a so called "happy case". But you always have to think a step further. What if there is no such element. and the if-condition covers this "path". Think abour you are coding server-based. Exceptions will ruin your day then. But when you code with foresight your always safer.

Comment: Cheers bro appreciate all the good help and knowledge :) best day ahead