# HTML number field setSelectionRange to retain the curser position doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, dom, angularjs-directive, html-input

I wan to retain my cursor position for my HTML number field.

```
    $(element).bind('keyup', function (e) {
           element.val(f($(this).val(),allowDecimals, false));
           this.setSelectionRange(0,1);
    });
```

As I understand this can be done in text fields but not in number fields.

[Updating an input's value without losing cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508707/updating-an-inputs-value-without-losing-cursor-position)

is there any way that I can obtain the current curser position and retain it in HTML number field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to avoid the number type and use a text type. 
http://blakeembrey.com/articles/angular-js-number-validation-bug/