# cursor getting jump in Redux-Form in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-form

I'm using Redux-form(8.2.6) with expo(34).whenever i entered any input value in **Field**, cursor getting jumped.I need to enter input slowly then only all input value entered correctly, otherwise input value getting render every time.

What am I doing wrong?

**My form**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import {
Container,
Item,
Input,
Header,
Body,
Content,
Title,
Button,
Text,
Label
} from "native-base";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
const validate = values => {
const error = {};
error.email = "";
error.name = "";
var ema = values.email;
var nm = values.name;
if (values.email === undefined) {
  ema = "";
}
if (values.name === undefined) {
  nm = "";
}
if (ema.length < 8 && ema !== "") {
  error.email = "too short";
}
if (!ema.includes("@") && ema !== "") {
  error.email = "@ not included";
}
if (nm.length > 8) {
  error.name = "max 8 characters";
}
return error;
};
class SimpleForm extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isReady: false
  };
  this.renderInput = this.renderInput.bind(this);
}

renderInput({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) {
  var hasError = false;
  if (error !== undefined) {
    hasError = true;
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <Item error={hasError} floatingLabel style={{paddingBottom:8}}>
        <Label>{label}</Label>
        <Input
          {...input}
          style={{ borderBottomWidth: 1.5, borderColor: "blue" }}
        />
      </Item>
      {hasError ? <Text>{error}</Text> : <Text />}
    </View>
  );
}
render() {
  const { handleSubmit, reset } = this.props;

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header>
        <Body>
          <Title>Redux Form</Title>
        </Body>
      </Header>
      <Content padder>
        <Field name="email" label="Email" component={this.renderInput} />
        <Field name="name" label="Name" component={this.renderInput} />
        <Button block primary>
          <Text>Submit</Text>
        </Button>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
}
export default reduxForm({
form: "test",
validate
})(SimpleForm);
```

I searched online but any solution didn't work.
anyone help me out from this issue.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: You can check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535688/stop-cursor-jumping-when-formatting-number-in-react/59188168#answer-59188168