# Ember observer not changing field value

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I'm new to Ember and have been doing some digging around for the a while looking for the answer to this.

What I have is a field and I want to restrict the use of whitespace (basically if the user hits the spacebar, I don't want it to do anything).

The issue, is that I can still hit the spacebar and add multiple spaces, and it's not until I hit another character that the value loses all the whitespace (To help this description, instead of swapping spaces, I'm going to swap the letter 'a').

So far I have an observer and a function (in my component js file):

```
emailChanged: Ember.observer('email', function() {
  // console.log('email changed');
  Ember.run.once(this, 'formatEmail');
}),

formatEmail() {
   // console.log('email', this.get('email')); 
   this.set('email', this.get('email').replace(/a/g, ''));
  // console.log('should be', this.get('email'));
},
```

So what is happening is that (when I use the console logs).

If I type a 'b' character in the console I get, `email changed`, then `email b`, then `should be b`.

When I type 'a', in the console I get `email changed` then `email ba`, then `formatEmail()` actually runs and changes the email, so then I get `should be b`, `email b`, `should be b`.

But it's still displaying 'ba'.

Hard to explain this, but basically, it looks like set is working, except that it's not changing what is displayed on the screen.

[Ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/9d8c765dcc31d2c8af50db3307746907?openFiles=components.form-field.js%2Ctemplates.components.form-field.hbs)

Comment: Can you show code how you bind email value to an input? Can you setup a demo on ember-twiddle.com?

Comment: @DanielKmak Yep, give me a sec and I'll try and set up a demo

Comment: @DanielKmak - I've added the [Ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/9d8c765dcc31d2c8af50db3307746907?openFiles=components.form-field.js%2Ctemplates.components.form-field.hbs)

Comment: FIxed it. Will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo on [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8c3bd4d7f1c482ebc05d0542ae988c55?openFiles=components.form-field.js%2Ctemplates.components.form-field.hbs).

I've changed a bit your input to handle email changes via an action instead of two-way-binding:

```
<input id='email' value={{email}} oninput={{action 'emailInput'}} />
```

And then in your component, I've added an action:

```
actions: {
    emailInput(event) {
        const $input = $(event.target);
        const value = $input.val();
        const withoutSpaces = value.replace(/\s+/g, '');

        this.set('email', withoutSpaces);
        $input.val(withoutSpaces);
    }
}
```

The key function here is using `.val()` to set input value:

```
$input.val(withoutSpaces);
```

Without it, the value in the input would not change.

Comment: Works great. I'm also mixing it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508707/updating-an-inputs-value-without-losing-cursor-position, so that the cursor doesn't change position.

Comment: Good stuff! Will remember if I encounter similar issue! Thanks!